# Convert a string to float or int

Tags: python

I'm new to programming so I hope you could help me with this.

I have a list like below:

```
a_list = ['0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4']
```

How can I convert the list which is a string to float or int format?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May I ask what the use for a List with only one Element is?

Comment: I was extracting multiple lines from a text file containing numbers it turned out to be a list with only one string element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
list(map(int, a_list[0].split(',')))
```

Result:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Riccardo Bucco! This resolved my problem.